# SQL- Remove Trailing space and add it to the beginning of the Name

Tags: sql, insert

Was working on SQL-EX.ru exercises.

There is one question for DML that I could not do, but I cannot proceed to the next one, until this one is done.

the question itself: **All the trailing spaces in the name column of the Battles table remove and add them at the beginning of the name.**

**My code:**
Update Battles
set name=concat(' ',(LTRIM(RTRIM(name))))

The system does not let it go through, I understand that I am using ' ' for the concat, whereas I need to use the stuff that got trimmed. And I have no idea how...
Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: Curious why this question was voted down?

Comment: I suspect each row has a different number of spaces otherwise what's the point, yes?  In other words, you need to move THE SAME spaces from the end to the front?  Does this SQL-EX support regular expressions?

Comment: @Gary_W you are right, it does support regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

Try Something Like:-

```
set name = lpad(trim(name), length(trim(name))+4, ' ')
```

Here use `TRIM` to remove space from both side. use `LPAD` to add something on left side with `n (4)` chars

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but the system does not recognize lpad or trim functions...

Comment: which system you are using?

Comment: The built-in system on SQL-ex.ru

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
set name = case when len(name) > len(rtrim(name))
            then replicate(' ', len(name) - len(rtrim(name))) + rtrim(name)
            else name
            end
```

Comment: "Your query returned the correct dataset on the first (available) database, but it returned incorrect dataset on the second checking database."
--- I got the same message with your code, as well as mine.
But thank you for the help!

Comment: I've edited the answer, try the new one. Also you have to look at the data to figure out what is going wrong and why this isn't working. Try running a select before updating to see why the dataset is incorrect.

Comment: Len() doesn't counting trailing spaces, to get it into count you need to reverse string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with SQL-EX.ru, but if it's Oracle compatible and you can use regular expressions (or you are at that point in the training) here's a way.  Maybe it'll give you an idea at least.  The first part is just setup and uses a WITH clause to create a table (like a temp table in memory, actually called a Common Table Expression or CTE) called battles containing a name column with 2 rows.  Each name column datum has a different number of spaces at the end.  Next select from that column using a regular expression that uses 2 "remembered" groups surrounded by parentheses, the first containing the string up to until but not including the first space, the second containing 0 or more space characters anchored to the end of the line.  Replace that with the 2nd group (the spaces) first, followed by the first group (the first part of the string).  This is surrounded by square brackets just to prove in the output the same spaces were moved to the front of the string.

```
SQL> with battles(name) as (
     select 'test2  ' from dual union
     select 'test1 '  from dual
   )
   select '[' || regexp_replace(name, '(.*?)([ ]*)$', '\2\1') || ']' fixed
   from battles;

FIXED
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ test1]
[  test2]

SQL>
```

I hope this solution can be applied to your problem or at least give you some ideas.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. I went through a good thinking process to do it, I appreciate it. However, it doesn't work, nor my co-workers could think of the solution. I wrote a ticket to the web-site, will see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
update battles
set name = case when (len(name+'a')-1) > len(rtrim(name))
        then 
replicate(' ', 
(len(name+'a')-1) - len(rtrim(name))) + rtrim(name)
        else name
        end
```

Len() doesn't count trailing spaces. So using (len(name+'a')-1).

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer:

```
UPDATE Battles
SET name = SPACE(DATALENGTH(name)-DATALENGTH(RTRIM(name))) + RTRIM(name)
```

But only works because name is VARCHAR.

More generic is to do:

```
UPDATE Battles
SET name = SPACE(len(name+'x')-1-len(RTRIM(name))) + RTRIM(name)
```

Answer (score -1):

simple example below ... enjoy :)

update battles set name =

Space( DATALENGTH(name) - DATALENGTH(rtrim(name))) + rtrim(name)

where date in ( select date from battles)